# How to access this keyword within new style anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Consider a very simple snippet of HTML and some slightly different methods of assigning an event handler to the HTML `SELECT` element. The problem lies with the use of anonymous functions of the form `( e )=>{ alert( this.value ) }`

```
<select name='radius'>
    <option>1
    <option>2
    <option>3
    <option>4
    <option>5
    <option>10
</select>



<script>
    /*
        this works fine, as you'd expect
    */
    const changehandler=function(e){
        alert( this.value + ' '+e.target )
    }
    document.querySelector( 'select[name="radius"]' ).addEventListener( 'change', changehandler );


    /*
        this works fine using `this` within the event handler when using the more traditional
        anonymous function
    */
    document.querySelector( 'select[name="radius"]' ).addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
        alert( this.value )
    });


    /*
        this does not work as expected. `this` does not refer to the HTML element in this
        case - it now refers to `[object Window]`
    */
    document.querySelector( 'select[name="radius"]' ).addEventListener( 'change', e=>{
        alert( this.value )
    });
</script>
```

I thought I might be able to `bind` to the HTML element, like this:

```
let select=document.querySelector( 'select[name="radius"]' );
    select.addEventListener( 'change', e=>{ alert( this ) }.bind( select ) );
```

This however causes an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

So, the question is can I access `this` keyword in these new style anonymous functions somehow and for it to refer to the HTML element to which the event handler is assigned? Is there some little trick I have overlooked?

Comment: That's what arrow functions are *for*; they don't bind their own scope. When that's not the behavior you want, use the "traditional" function declarations.

Comment: Ok, thanks @DanielBeck - I guess there must be text somewhere on the interwebs to make that known but I know not where. Looks like traditional style is the only way in certain instances then.

Comment: Function declarations are function declarations. Function expressions are function expressions. Arrow functions are arrow functions. They are all different tools for different jobs. There isn't a "traditional / new" divide.

Comment: ok - thanks for pointing out the differences - or suggesting the duplicate by@FelixKling. Knwing that they were / are called "arrow functions" would have helped find the answer without having to bug the high heid yins of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, **although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Arrow functions are useful when you want to retain the parent scope; if you need the function to have its own `this`, use the "traditional" `function() {...}` structure.